# ICriteria adding Or Restrictions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I need to do a select as follows

```
select * from produtos where Value = 10 or Value = 15 or  Value= 20 ....
```

being that I do not know how many values ​​will come, it will be in a loop on a list that the user will decide how many values ​​will be ... the problem is that if I do Criteria

```
ICriteria criterion = session.createCriteria(typeof (Product) "produto"). SetCacheable (true);
criterio.Add (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 10));
criterio.Add (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 15));
criterio.Add (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 20));
```

is made with a select clause "and"

```
select * from produtos where Value=10 and Value = 15 and  Value= 20 ....
```

can not use the Restriction "in" because I can have place in the Restrictions.Eq  Restrictions.Ge or Restrictions.Le or any other clause ...

There is some way to go just adding clauses in Criteria? something like

```
criteria.Add (Restrictions.Or (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 10)));
criteria.Add (Restrictions.Or (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 15)));
criteria.Add (Restrictions.Or (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 20)));
criteria.Add (Restrictions.Or (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 25)));
```

I understand that it uses some kind of expression like link but did not understand how this could help me to go riding a select, for example, say I have a foreach and for each item I need to get this foreach adding an "or" in the criteria,

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    criteria.Add("or item.Valor =" item.Valor);
}
```

I can only criteria in this:

```
foreach (var item in items)    
{
    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("item.Valor", item.Valor));
}
```

What would a "and" or it. But that would not or could add another criteria to that.

I would have wanted that over the same situations

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var items = session.QueryOver<Item>()
                       .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.Valor item.Valor == | |?)
                       .List<Item>();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `QueryOver` API? :)

Comment: sorry did not know this ... Can you give me an example of how the code would be in C # if possible

Comment: Oh, [here's a whole article](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx) on the subject, enjoy :) NHibernate has also a separate LINQ provider built in, which you may also check out if you want...

Comment: Disjunction it's what i needed... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try :

```
criteria.Add (
    new Disjunction()
        .Add (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 10))
        .Add (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 15))
        .Add (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 20))
        .Add (Restrictions.Eq ("produto.Valor", 25))
    );
```

I guess `criteria.Add (Restrictions.In("produto.Valor", new[]{10,15,20,25});` should also work

Hope this will help

Comment: yes this work... disjuntion for "or" conjunction for "and"... thanks!!